# Calling C# DLL from LUA Script Environment

Tags: c#, dll, lua

I am programming in `Lua 5.0.2` script language and I want to load my own `C# DLL` and call it's function in my Lua code.

This function is such as below:

```
string Concat(string S1, string S2)
{
   return S1+S2;
}
```

Is there anyway to reach this goal?
Help me Please.

Comment: http://techneilogy.blogspot.de/2012/02/compiling-lua-with-visual-studio-2010.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288621/can-a-c-dll-file-be-loaded-in-lua

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381565/how-to-create-a-custom-net-dll-loadable-for-luaforwindows

Comment: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LoadLibrary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856826/c-sharp-external-library-lua-call-problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C#, but you can first try using this answer to call C# functions from C: [Calling C# from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428267/calling-c-sharp-from-c)

After you do that, you can create Lua C functions that call the C# functions, and load those as normal.